# WebApplication Context files on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, deployment, context.xml

I have a download service served using Tomcat 5.5.15. It is created by adding an XML file in **$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost**. E.g ***downloads.xml*** for ***http://example.com/app.downloads/***

```
<Context path="/app.downloads" docBase="Z:\Sites\example.com\downloads\"/>
```

After Tomcat restart the context file is sometimes deleted(not always), and I have to manually recreate the file.

What could be the problem? Is there a was of fixing it?

Comment: Are you deploying the web app from a .war file? If yes, create the context.xml inside the war file.

Comment: i'm not using a war file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the normal case. I also don't expect that you're deploying a WAR for a simple download service. I think that your Tomcat instance is controlled by something else, for example an IDE such as Eclipse. You shouldn't do that for production as well. If you run Tomcat standalone, the problem should be solved.

Comment: tomcat is running as a standalone install (no string attached).

Comment: Then I don't see any other option than declaring it inside `<host>` of `server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Tomcat. I filed a report for Tomcat 5 but the fix is complicated.

The file is removed during re-deploy, not restart. So you need to make sure your app doesn't get re-deployed. Don't change your app while server is running.

Comment: is it possible to send me the fix?

Comment: No. The problem is complicated. Tomcat is confused between 3 different deployment modes (Fragment, WAR, directory) and it requires changes in many places to fix it. So I never came up with a patch. Until a fix, don't use this deployment method in production.